# How to override Datagrid cell style in XAML?

Tags: wpf

I have a style defined in app.xaml as below:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property= "BorderThickness" Value="1"/>            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Grid Height="18">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".2" >
                                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="#992288ff" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".2">
                                      ......
                      ......
                  ......
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
```

In my form, I have a style defined for one cell. The code is below:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource FGColorKey}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Here I am defining only the foreground style only. But the style I defined in the app.xaml for the cell template is not applied for this cell. please see the image attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting the `CellStyle` property on the column, that style will be used for every cell in that column, and the system will no longer care about the style you have defined as a resource .

To apply both styles, you have to base the one in the cellstyle on the one in your resources in app.xaml.

You do that by setting the `BasedOn` property on the style like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource FGColorKey}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```